# Show the percentage of companies with and without crowdfunding

Tags: postgresql

I want to show the percentage of companies with crowdfunding vs. companies without crowdfunding. I tried below but I just can't get it to work.

```
WITH with_crowdfunding AS
    (SELECT COUNT(market) 
    FROM investment_finance
    WHERE equity_crowdfunding > 0),
no_crowdfunding AS
    (SELECT COUNT(market) 
    FROM investment_finance
    WHERE equity_crowdfunding = 0),
total_companies AS
    (SELECT COUNT(market)total_companies
    FROM investment_finance)
SELECT
    market,ROUND(with_crowdfunding/total_companies,0)* 100 percent
    FROM investment_finance;
```

expected:

```
       ?              COUNT          PERCENTAGE
with_crowdfunding         5             5%
no_crowdfunding         100            95%
```

Comment: Please update your question with what you are receiving when you run the query

Comment: here's the error:

ERROR:  column "with_crowdfunding" does not exist

LINE 13:     market,ROUND(with_crowdfunding/total_companies,0)* 100 p...
                          ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 341

Answer (score 0):

Virtual tables are being created by the WITH statement, `with_crowdfunding` for example. Virtual tables need to have their columns referenced in the select statement, such as: `with_crowdfunding.count`. The way the query in your question is written there isn't anything to join the virtual tables on, so UNION on the select statement needs to be used.

One possible solution is

```sql
WITH with_crowdfunding AS
    (SELECT COUNT(market) 
    FROM investment_finance
    WHERE equity_crowdfunding > 0),
no_crowdfunding AS
    (SELECT COUNT(market) 
    FROM investment_finance
    WHERE equity_crowdfunding = 0),
total_companies AS
    (SELECT COUNT(market) total_companies
    FROM investment_finance)
SELECT
   'With crowdfunding' market, 
ROUND((with_crowdfunding.count/total_companies.total_companies) * 100 ,0) percent
    FROM with_crowdfunding, total_companies
UNION
SELECT
  'No Crowdfunding' market, 
ROUND((no_crowdfunding.count/total_companies.total_companies  * 100),0) percent
    FROM no_crowdfunding, total_companies
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH with_crowdfunding AS
    (SELECT cast(COUNT(market) as varchar(128))
    FROM investment_finance
    WHERE equity_crowdfunding > 0),
no_crowdfunding AS
    (SELECT cast(COUNT(market) as varchar(128))
    FROM investment_finance
    WHERE equity_crowdfunding = 0),
total_companies AS
    (SELECT COUNT(market)total_companies
    FROM investment_finance)
SELECT
    market,ROUND(with_crowdfunding/total_companies,0)* 100 percent
    FROM with_crowdfunding,no_crowdfunding  ;
```